# pandas exporting to excel without format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I would like to export data from dataframe to an excel, that has already its format-layout (colours, cells, etc.)

This code overwrite the all sheet, instead I would like the export data without changing excel layout.

is that possible?

## Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/pandas_positioning.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_data',
         startrow=7, startcol=4, header=False, index=False)
```

## Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.

```
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually.

Example:

```
WB = 'C:/pandas_positioning.xlsx'
WS = 'my_data'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(WB, engine='openpyxl')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(WB)
wb.create_sheet(WS)
writer.book = wb
writer.sheets = {x.title: x for x in wb.worksheets}

ws = writer.sheets[WS]

for icol, col_name in zip(range(len(df.columns)+1), df.columns):
    ws.cell(1, icol+2, col_name)

for irow, row_name in zip(range(len(df.columns)+1), df.index):
    ws.cell(irow+2, 1, row_name)

for (_, row), icol in zip(df.iterrows(), range(len(df.index) + 1)):
    for (_, cell), c in zip(row.iteritems(), range(len(df.columns) + 1)):
        ws.cell(icol+2, c+2).value = cell

writer.save()
```